# Optimising For...Next loops in Select Case

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have three different `CASE`s in a bit of code, each of which has minor variations on a routine revolving around a `For...Next` loop. The question is, is there any difference in efficiency and speed depending on how I nest them?

In other words, is:

```
Select Case sPosition
    Case Is = "First"
        For j = 17 to 65
            [Do stuff]
        Next j
    Case Is = "Middle"
        For j = 17 to 65
            [Do stuff]
        Next j
    Case Is = "Last"
        For j = 17 to 65
            [Do stuff]
        Next j
End Select
```

...any more or less efficient than:

```
For j = 17 to 65
    Select Case sPosition
        Case Is = "First"
            [Do stuff]
        Case Is = "Middle"
            [Do stuff]
        Case Is = "Last"
            [Do stuff]
    End Select
Next j
```

Comment: I doubt there is a noticeable difference either way, but the second one will loop no matter what and the first one will not enter the loop in the event that  `sPosition` is none of "First," "Middle" or "Last".

Comment: Can't resist it - your second example will fail without an `End Select` :D

Comment: Hah, yes. The one in the project has one. :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More of a question for CodeReview than SO, but regardless, it is dependent on what you are intending to do with the loops.  In the first situation, you have a condition and then you loop through the data in accordance with the result of the condition, doing the same thing for all the data.  In the second case, you are re-checking the condition each time the loop runs.  If you think different things will be happening as the loop runs (different Cases being selected), then you need to use the second variation, but if the checked condition is not changing, then the first option will be faster, as the condition is only checked once for the loop

Comment: whether or not the speed difference is noticeable depends on the size of your data set and the size of the loops, but technically the first scenario will run faster than the second

Comment: Excellent - that's exactly the detail I needed to know. Many thanks to both you and @lancer102rus.

Answer (score 1):

I think first variant is more efficient because select case works only one time and in the second variant select case works for every step of cicle (49 times)

Comment: That's what I assumed - I'm still getting started at this, so optimisation is still an arcane art to me. :-D

Comment: In VBA what takes the most processing time is references to the Workbook/Worksheets/Range (etc) objects. Processing time for a variable check is very low, that's not where most of your efficiency can be gained. Usually you want to minimise references to the aforementioned objects.

Comment: Good advice - so far most of my things have been working directly with cells, so I think I'll start trying to do my calculations in the VBA rather than the sheet. Thanks!